# Neo4J front end for movie example

Tags: neo4j

I am looking at the Neo4J example here :

https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j-4

This only contains .java source files.
Where is the code for the front end?  Is it in a jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frontend is a simple static HTML page that uses jQuery and d3. It is part of the Github repository in the `src/main/resources/static` directory. Specifically, [this file](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j-4/blob/master/src/main/resources/static/index.html).

More information about this example project is available on the [Neo4j Developer Resources site](http://neo4j.com/developer/example-project/)

Comment: Thanks. Have a follow up Q. Where did the "search" part in the path for http://localhost:8080/movies/search/findByTitleContaining come from? I see the "findByTitleContaining" part defined in MovieRepistory.java but not the "search" part.